# How to Get ROP4 Mask bit?

Tags: winapi, drivers, printers

I am working on printer driver sample which capture GDI call such as DrvBitBlt(), DrvTextOut() … etc. In DrvBitBlt i am getting ROP4 value as 0XF0F0. It mean to say that we need to use the brush object.

When I read the DrvBitBlt() ROP4 the documentation says:

> The low byte specifies a Rop3 that should be calculated if the mask is
>   one, and the high byte specifies a Rop3 that can be calculated and
>   applied if the mask is 0.

My question is where the mask value will be present. How go get the mask bit is 0 or 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mask bits come from the third parameter to [DrvBitBlt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa447732.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the replay, so 1st bit in psoMask need to be mapped with 1st bit of destination(and/or  source), and 2nd bit in psoMask need to be mapped with 2nd bit in destination(and/or source) .....

Comment: Sort of. psoMask should refer to a bitmap with 1 bit per pixel. The source and destination may (and probably are) bitmaps with >1 bit per pixel. So the 1st bit in the psoMask bitmap maps to the 1st PIXEL of the source / destination.